# How can I render a template and link to a particular section of the page?

Tags: django, django-templates, django-views

In my question_detail_solution.html I have got this div:

```
<div id='answer'></div>
```

When I render the template in views.py I want something like an html anchor link to this div.
What is the solution? This doesn't work:

```
return render(request, 'tasks/question_detail_solution.html#answer', context)
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to pass link in `context` as,

```
context['link'] = 'https://stackoverflow.com/'
```

And in HTML,

```
<div id='answer'>{{link}}</div>
```

Comment: I think this only creates an link in the div? In my case I have got a long page with questions and a submit button at the end. If the user clicks on this button the page reloads with the answers. By default the scrollbar is at the top but than the user has to scroll down again to see the answers. So I want to render the template and scroll down to the div. In "normal" HTML I can do it with www.website.com#section.